# Parameters in woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button hook

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, actions

I need pass parameters to woocommerce **woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button** hook.

In my functions, I have a function that calls:

```
/** Yiith: evitar pagar dos veces por el mismo depósito, obliga a completar pedido primero **/
if( defined( 'YITH_WCDP' ) && ! function_exists( 'yith_wcdp_skip_deposit_if_there_is_other_deposit' ) ){
function yith_wcdp_skip_deposit_if_there_is_other_deposit( $process_deposit, $product_id ){
    /**
    * @var $product \WC_Product
    */
    if(!is_user_logged_in()){
        add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'yith_print_link_force_login');
        $process_deposit = false;
    }
    else{
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();

        $order_ids = yith_get_order_ids_from_bought_items ( $product_id, $user_id );

        foreach ( $order_ids as $order_id ){

            $suborders         = YITH_WCDP_Suborders()->get_suborder( $order_id );
            if ( is_array( $suborders ) && !empty( $suborders ) ){
                foreach ( $suborders as $suborder_id ) {
                    $suborder = wc_get_order( $suborder_id );

                    if (!in_array( $suborder->get_status() , array(
                        'completed',
                        'processing',
                        ))) {
                            add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'yith_print_link');                             //do_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', $order_id);
                            $process_deposit = false;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $process_deposit;
}
add_filter( 'yith_wcdp_is_deposit_enabled_on_product', 'yith_wcdp_skip_deposit_if_there_is_other_deposit', 10, 2 );
}
```

And it must call yith_print_link, wich looks like:

```
if( defined( 'YITH_WCDP' ) && ! function_exists( 'yith_print_link' ) ) {
function yith_print_link($order)
{
    if($order != null){
        $order = "view-order/" . $order . "/#yith_wcdp_deposits_details";
    }
    else{
        $order = "orders/";
    }
    $link = get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id')) . $order;
    echo '<div class="buy-link"><a href="' . $link . '">Pagar matrícula</a></div><style>.single_add_to_cart_button.qbutton.button.alt{display: none!important;}</style>';
    echo '<p style="font-weight: 200;">Tienes la plaza pagada, finaliza la matrícula.</p>';
}
}
```

I'm trying to show a link to an specific order before the cart button in product page if the current logged user had bought this product before.

Thanks, and Regards.

Comment: Where is `$order` coming from? Don't you actually need to find the order first?

Comment: Hi, I edited the code. I already know $order_id, wich is the data I need to pass to action.